# How can I get an IP in engine.io?

Tags: javascript, websocket, socket.io

I'm using the engine.io framework for an app I'm working on and I'm having some trouble. I've been trying to get the clients IP. I'm currently using:

```
socket.transport.socket.upgradeReq.headers['x-forwarded-for']
```

But that only works once the user has sent an upgradeRequest, If he dosn't send and upgrade request then I can't get his IP. Is there any other alternative.
Thanks,
@_C1D